# Inserting an id of specific array value which did not exist in Table A and inserting in Table B

Tags: android, sqlite

I have three table: symptoms, disease, symDisease

```
|   Disease   |     |  Symptoms  |     | symDisease   |
---------------     --------------     ----------------
|    id(pk)   |     |    id(pk)  |     | diseaseId(fk)|
|    name     |     |    symp    |     | symptomId(fk)|
```

**Code that checks existence of value in array and inserts into Database:**

```
 public  Cursor checkExistence(){
    Cursor c=null;
    String[] values={"headache","heartburns"};
    SQLiteDatabase db= getReadableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (String value : values) {
            long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,
                    TABLE_SYMPTOMS, COLUMN_SYMP+" = ?", new String[] { value });
            if (count == 0) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(COLUMN_SYMP, value);
                db.insert(TABLE_SYMPTOMS, null, cv);
            }
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    return c;

}
```

The code above checks to see if values in `String[] values={"headache","heartburns"};` exist in table symptoms. In this case `headache` exist but `heartburns` doesn't exist in table symptoms,so it is inserted into the table.

Now would like to get the id of `heartburns` and insert it in to table symDisease  along with a `diseaseid`. Example the `diseaseid of Malaria = 1`.
So at the end of the insertion in Table symDisease it should be like `(idOfMalaria, idOfHeartburns)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get de ID of the row inserted with:

```
long rowInserted = db.insert(TABLE_SYMPTOMS, null, cv);
if (rowInserted != -1) {
    //New row was added correctly, and the id of the inserted 
    //value is in rowInserted.

}else{
    //Error on inserted
}
```